# Socks proxy not working for streaming

Tags: networking, socks-proxy

I'm trying to look at landlocked TV content in another country, it's freely available on the internet but it says it's only accessible inside the country. This is quite annoying. So I've set up a VPN over there and I can access the content without any problems.

Rather than using VPN I'd like to use a SOCKS proxy because my media center, based on XBMC, makes it really easy to configure. Well, nothing easier than install [dante server](http://blog.edseek.com/~jasonb/articles/dante_tunnel.shtml), except that it doesn't work...

When testing on my compute (OSX) I check my IP with one of those fancy whatsmyip websites, it reports I'm in the country my proxy is set up in, but the content I'd like to watch still detects I'm not... how come? Mind you that with VPN there isn't any problems at all, I can access the content I want just as if I was there. I must say I don't understand everything I'm doing, but I suspect not all connections go through the proxy.

Does anybody know how to test if my connections indeed go through the proxy? I've set up the settings in the preference panel on OSX and I'm using Chrome that reports it's using the system wide settings.

**Edit**: while continuing my search I came to understand RTMP streams are [not routed through web based proxies](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4262734), why would my media center have this option then is beyond me... So I guess I'll have to set up a VPN client on my media center since it's proven to work.

**Edit 2**: for the person that will have the same issue in 6 years the step-by-step configuration I followed to set up a VPN client on my system (Raspbmc on Raspberry Pi) is [here](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=1754).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is that streaming over RTMP is not possible over socks, use VPN instead.